# Python: How can I filter a n-nested dict of dicts by leaf value?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I've got a dict that looks something like this:

```
d = {'Food': {'Fruit'  : {'Apples'    : {'Golden Del.'  : ['Yellow'],
                                         'Granny Smith' : ['Green'],
                                         'Fuji'         : ['Red'],    
                                        },
                          'Cherries'  : ['Red'],
                          'Bananas'   : ['Yellow'],
                          'Grapes'    : {'Red Grapes'   : ['Red'],
                                         'Green Grapes' : ['Green'],  
                                        },
                          },
              'Dessert': {'Baked Ds' : {'Cakes'         : {'Yellow Cake' : ['Yellow'],
                                                           'Red Velvet'  : ['Red'],
                                                          },
                                         'Cookies'      : ['Yellow'],
                                        },
                          },
              'Steak'  : ['Red'],
             },
     'Other': ['Blue'],
    }
```

So basically, an n-nested dict, where each value is either another dict or a list containing a single item.

Let's say that I want to filter this by a single list item, say, 'Red' such that the result would be:

```
d = {'Food': {'Fruit'  : {'Apples'    : {'Fuji'        : ['Red'],    
                                        },
                          'Cherries'  : ['Red'],
                          'Grapes'    : {'Red Grapes'  : ['Red'], 
                                        },
                          },
              'Dessert': {'Baked Ds' : {'Cakes'        : {'Red Velvet'  : ['Red'],
                                                          },
                                        },
                          },
              'Steak'  : ['Red'],
             },
    }
```

So that the structure remains the same but everything that doesn't have 'Red' as its list item is removed, all the way up the hierarchy.

Any suggestions? I've messed around with this for a while and came up with this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
def filterNestedDict(node, searchItem):
    if isinstance(node,list):
        return node
    else:
        for key, value in node.iteritems():
            if isinstance(value,dict) and value is not {}:
                return {key: filterNestedDict(value,searchItem)}
            elif searchItem in value:
                return {key: filterNestedDict(value,searchItem)}

return filterNestedDict(bigTree, searchItem)
```

I suspect it's just an issue of recursion, but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: is there a reason why the leaves are 1-value lists instead of just strings?

Comment: wx.TreeListCtrl is the reason.

Comment: those dictionary definitions look nice +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were pretty close, this should do the trick for you:

```
def filter_nested_dict(node, search_term):
    if isinstance(node, list):
        if node[0] == search_term:
            return node
        else:
            return None
    else:
        dupe_node = {}
        for key, val in node.iteritems():
            cur_node = filter_nested_dict(val, search_term)
            if cur_node:
                dupe_node[key] = cur_node
        return dupe_node or None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Mapping


def yield_values_2(d):
  for key in d.keys():
    if isinstance(d[key], Mapping):
      yield_values_2(d[key]) 
      if not d[key]:
        del d[key]
    elif d[key] != ["Red"]:
      del d[key]

d = {'Food': {'Fruit'  : {'Apples'    : {'Fuji'        : ['Red'], 'Fuji2': ['Blue']    
                                        },
                                                                  'Cherries'  : ['Red'],
                                                                                            'Grapes'    : {'Red Grapes'  : ['Red'], 
                                                                                                                                    },
                                                                                                                                                              },
                                                                                                                                                                            'Dessert': {'Baked Ds' : {'Cakes'        : {'Red Velvet'  : ['Red'],
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      },
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              },
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        },
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      'Steak'  : ['Red'],
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   },
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       }

print d
yield_values_2(d)
print d
```

Comment: Nitpick: there's no need to include the dictionary in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `NestedDict`.

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict

d = {'Food': {'Fruit'  : {'Apples'    : {'Golden Del.'  : ['Yellow'],
                                         'Granny Smith' : ['Green'],
                                         'Fuji'         : ['Red'],    
                                        },
                          'Cherries'  : ['Red'],
                          'Bananas'   : ['Yellow'],
                          'Grapes'    : {'Red Grapes'   : ['Red'],
                                         'Green Grapes' : ['Green'],  
                                        },
                          },
              'Dessert': {'Baked Ds' : {'Cakes'         : {'Yellow Cake' : ['Yellow'],
                                                           'Red Velvet'  : ['Red'],
                                                          },
                                         'Cookies'      : ['Yellow'],
                                        },
                          },
              'Steak'  : ['Red'],
             },
     'Other': ['Blue'],
    }
nd = NestedDict(d)

nd_filtered = NestedDict()
for key, value in nd.items():
    if value == ["Red"]:
        nd_filtered[key] = value
```

To get the result as a dictionary

```
>>> nd_filtered.to_dict()
{'Food': {'Dessert': {'Baked Ds': {'Cakes': {'Red Velvet': ['Red']}}},
          'Fruit': {'Apples': {'Fuji': ['Red']},
                    'Cherries': ['Red'],
                    'Grapes': {'Red Grapes': ['Red']}},
          'Steak': ['Red']}}
```

To install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) `pip install ndicts`